# Вставляю сниппет падает сайт с 500 ошибкой Modx Revolution

Tags: modx

```
[[!getImageList?
    &tvname=`materials`
    &tpl=`sostav-kyxni`]]
```

Причем нее первый раз такое наблюдаю. Был старый сайт, все работало и вот недавно страницы с getimagelist упали. Может, конечно, я там добавил где лишнюю запятую, но это маловероятно. С чем может быть связана такая проблема?

Comment: не первый раз такое причем, был старый сайт все работало и вот недавно страницы с getimagelist упали, может конечно я там добавил, где лишнюю запятую, но это маловероятно, с чем может быть связана такая проблема

Comment: Что в логах modx (core/cache/logs/) по ошибке?